# I want a text counter to work on my page without using jquery?

Tags: javascript

I want a text counter that will instantly count the characters in textarea and display them in textarea_feedback.

Ideally it would count to 160, then when it hits 160 it would go back to 0 and start counting again.

So far i've gotten this, which isn't working

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('textarea').onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('textarea_feedback').innerHTML = "Characters left: " + (500 - this.value.length);
  };
})
```

Comment: `document` doesn't have `load` event, use `window` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first line doesn't work.

Remove `document.addEventListener('load', function()` and just put your code at the end of the `<body>`.

```js
function updateText () {
      feedback.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + (500 - textArea.value.length);
  };

var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('textarea_feedback');

textArea.onkeyup = function(){ updateText() };
textArea.onpaste = function(){ updateText() };
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```

Comment: Small issue: the counter won't increment when users paste text per context menu

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code. Sorry for the delay, but I had an accident and I'm now at the hospital (Nothing too bad)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Using the remainder operator will let you start over from 0. And the `load` event is fired on the `window` object not on `document`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById('textarea').onkeyup = function () {
    var charsLeft = 160 - this.value.length % 160;
    document.getElementById('textarea_feedback').innerHTML = "Characters left: " + charsLeft;
  };
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```

Comment: Small issue: the counter won't increment when users paste text per context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/input) event to capture all changes to the input's value by pasting, undoing, autofill etc.:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('textarea'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('textarea_feedback');

input.addEventListener('input', event => {
  var remaining = 160 - (event.target.value.length % 160);
  feedback.textContent = `${remaining} characters remaining`;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```